# PHP While Loop dealing with last item in loop

Tags: php, sql, while-loop, count

I have the following code:

```
$query6 = "SELECT TIMESTAMP As sDate, COUNT( TIMESTAMP ) AS Total 
           FROM tresults GROUP BY TO_DAYS( timestamp ) ";

$result6 = $mysqli->query($query6);

while($row6 = $result6->fetch_row())
    {
        $dt = new DateTime($row6[0]);
        $sd = $dt->format('M j');

        echo "['".$sd."',  ".$row6[1]."],";

    }
```

This works fine, but what I am struggling with is that I need the `echo` to be different the for the last one in the loop.  It needs to be (the comma is missing after the `]` for reference):

```
    echo "['".$sd."',  ".$row6[1]."]";
```

I've been trying to do a count of the number of arrays but cannot get that to work.  Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: You could just add them into an array (`$yourArray[] = "['".$sd."',  ".$row6[1]."]";`) then `implode(',', $yourArray)` after your `while` statement.

Comment: You could do that but what about much simpler: call `substr($sd, 0, -1)` after the while?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the total number of rows and define a counter. After that you can compare them in the loop :

```
$result6 = $mysqli->query($query6);
$num = $resut6->num_rows;
$i = 0;
while($row6 = $result6->fetch_row())
{
    if($num != $i){
       /* code for all elements except the last one*/
    } else {
       /* code for the last element*/
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Or you can do something like this using [**implode()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) :

```
$final = array();
while($row6 = $result6->fetch_row()){
    $dt = new DateTime($row6[0]);
    $final[] =  "['" . $dt->format('M j') . "',  ".$row6[1]."]";
}
echo implode(', ', $final);
```

Comment: Perfect (small change to variable need from $resukt6 to $result6!